# Formatting the body of an email sent with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I implemented javascript code in a simple html form I was creating using the mailto: function. However simple formatting doesn't seem to work as the body text is added by writing &body=... I was wondering if it was possible to add line splitting (/n doesn't seem to work) or even put a table in?

Comment: Please post your whole code in here, also, I assume this is in node?

Comment: `mailto:` is pretty much a hack. it is NOT a mail client, and you should NOT be trying to send complex emails via that. You can't provide the necessary mimeheaders for the generated email to tell the recipient that it is an html email anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending email by placing an `<a href="mailto:..."></a>` link in your HTML document has nothing to do with JavaScript.

You may try url-encoding a bare line feed (`%0A`):

```
<a href="mailto:foo@example.com?subject=Test&amp;body=One%0ATwo%0AThree">Send</a>
```

... but of course there's absolutely no guarantee that whatever tool chosen by the browser to process the link will do what you want.

Comment: I worded it poorly, I used javascript to pull and analyze info from my html form, the mailto function I know is not javascript. Your suggestion worked for my purposes though, thanks!